# Connect to a https site with a given p12 certificate

Tags: java, https, certificate

The server side gave me a `.p12` certificate file which I've clicked and installed on my machine and then I can access the `HTTPS` site through browser. Now they want me to crawl their site with the certificate given. I'm stuck at the very first stage of it, trying to get the `inputStream` from the `httpsURLConnection`. The site has no login. It only checks if you have the certificate or not.

What I've done so far was to use Firefox to export out the certificate in a `.crt` file format. Then I used the keytool command to import it (the `.crt` file, not the `.p12`) into java keystore. Then in the code:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
File ksFile = new File(keystorePath);
in = new FileInputStream(ksFile);
ks.load(in, "changeit".toCharArray());
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(certificateAlias);

SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) (new URL(urlString)).openConnection();
con.connect();
con.getInputStream();
con.disconnect();
```

The `getInputStream()` will give me 403 error forbidden access. I've searched through other related topics and are actually deeply more confused than before reading them. Would greatly appreciate answers.

Additional Details:

- I've only just instantiated the certificate, and have not let the program knows any sort of keys (private, public, etc.). So what I believe I must present these keys to the server, letting it know I'm actually holding the certificate. I have absolutely no idea how to do this, both logic and syntax wise.
- I've tried keytool command to import the .p12 cert file into the keystore but somehow, the -pkcs12 option is not recognized by the keytool. Any idea on how to directly use this .p12 cert would be great as well.
- trustAllCert is a one element array of TrustMangers which does not validate anything (trust all). I don't know if I should continue to use this. In fact, now I actually have a single cert to trust. What is the proper way to write a trustManger in this case?
- I have no control over the server side. All I was given are the URL to access their site, which is under HTTPS protocol, and a .p12 certificate. The site has no login. If the certificate is installed, I can go in.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you want to attempt to code up the SSL configuration, you could use the P12 file given to you without having to convert it into a JKS. Also, you will need to use the private key in the P12, and not just the certificates that you copied into the JKS. Not sure if this will suit your needs directly, but this may put you on the right path:

```
        KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        clientStore.load(new FileInputStream("test.p12"), "testPass".toCharArray());

        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(clientStore, "testPass".toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        trustStore.load(new FileInputStream("cacerts"), "changeit".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] tms = tmf.getTrustManagers();

        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(kms, tms, new SecureRandom());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        URL url = new URL("https://www.testurl.com");

        HttpsURLConnection urlConn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Configuring the trustStore this way is optional. You could create a JKS with all of the certificates in the chain of your P12, or just make sure they are in your JRE's cacerts file. As for keytool, for reference, you can run keytool commands on a P12 (specify -storetype pkcs12), but cannot import a P12 into a JKS. You also cannot export just a key from a P12 with the keytool command.

I have no servers setup at the moment to test out this code, so give it a shot and see if you still receive the 403 error.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks a lot. This sort out the problem for me perfectly. So all there is to this was that I missed the key mangers part?

Comment: I'm quite new to this topic and don't understand the part of the JKS Keystore. I also have just a p12 File but I dont know how I can get the JKS File. Any help would be great.

Comment: In my case, I needed `sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");` instead.

Comment: This answer solved my issues, too. Thanks a lot, @bobz32!

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me:

```
   KeyStore keyStore  = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File("client-p12-keystore.p12"));
    try {
        keyStore.load(instream, "password".toCharArray());
    } finally {
        instream.close();
    }

    // Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, "password".toCharArray())
        //.loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy())
        .build();
    // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
        sslcontext,
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
        .build();
    try {

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://localhost:8443/secure/index");

        System.out.println("executing request" + httpget.getRequestLine());

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        try {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            if (entity != null) {
                System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
            }
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Adding this as an answer as I need more space to write.

First, a question: Is the certificate signed by a trusted authority such as Verisign? If it's not, the truststore should have the CA Certificate (usually a .pem file) which makes the p12 cert 'valid'. The default java trust store contains most (if not all) of the CA certificates from the big companies, such as Verisign and Thawte.

Also, you can test your app to connect to the secure server without coding the SSL configuration, but with some command line parameters, for example:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=[path_to_p12_cert] \
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=[p12_password] \
 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12 \
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=[path_to_trust_store_with_CA_certificates] \
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=[trust_store_password] \
 [MainClass]
```

and then your code becomes just

```
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) (new URL(urlString)).openConnection();
con.connect();
con.getInputStream();
con.disconnect();
```

If you feel masochistic, the [JSSE ref guide](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) is great fun.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. How the certificate is generated is out of my knowledge. My guess is that the server is using keytool -genkey or some sort of self-signed or easy to create certificate. For the keystore, the cacerts file (default I believe) was empty. The cert I imported in is the only certificate inside at the moment. Even when I moved the file out of the $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security, I could still go into the website normally. I'll look into the guide you linked.

Comment: You can see the Issuing Authority in firefox. Go to the website, and click to the left of the address bar. A pop up appears, click on "more information", click on the "security" tab.  Then click on "view certificate" and check the information where it says "issued by". If that's not one of the global trusted CA authorities, then you'll need to get that CA certificate and create a trust store with the CA cert.

Comment: Hi. I checked the issuer and it turns out to be Entrust, Inc. I believe it's a global trusted CA authority. Which is unfortunate for my case for your advice is for the case when it is not?

Comment: Entrust is not in the default cacerts file (it's located in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts), at least in the JDK 1.6.26. You can list all the CA certs by running the command `keytool -list -keystore cacerts` in the same folder. I think you can download the CA certificates from Entrust from [this](http://www.entrust.net/developer/index.cfm) page. You need only one of the certificates, check name of the certificate in firefox and there should be one that matches in the site.

Comment: Hi again. That unfortunately doesn't help. The certificate turns out to be a chain of 3 certs. The root is Entrust 2048 and I got it imported from the site you linked. The intermediate one is Entrust Certification Authority L1B which I have no idea how to get. The last one is what I'm given as a .p12 file. After installing the root 2048 cert, I still got 403 error. I believe I need to do something more than just importing all the necessary certs. Something like presenting to the server the certs / keys via some sort of requests or authentication?

Comment: Java should do it automatically, that's why it's possible to pass the certs from command line parameters and an app should work anyway. Sorry that I wans't able to be of much help. JSSE is dark art :(.

Comment: No problem. Your help was great =D. I can actually get in with SSLSocket (But not HttpsURLConnection). Maybe I'll try something with that.

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Spring, it could be reached by RestTemplate:

```
public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {
    KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
    InputStream resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("path_to_certificate.p12");
    clientStore.load(resource, "p12_password".toCharArray());

    SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = new SSLContextBuilder();
    sslContextBuilder.setProtocol("TLS");
    sslContextBuilder.loadKeyMaterial(clientStore, "p12_password".toCharArray());
    sslContextBuilder.loadTrustMaterial(new TrustSelfSignedStrategy());

    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContextBuilder.build());
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
        .build();
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple keytool command would export your .p12 keystore into .jks keystore:

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -deststoretype JKS -destkeystore keystore.jks`