# Java counterpart for ClientCredentials in C#?

Tags: c#, java, web-services, wsdl

I'm implementing a proxy towards a webservice in Java EE and I've generated stubs from a WSDL for the webservice. However, in the user manual for the webservice all the examples are in C#, and the manual says you have to set the ClientCredentials property on the auto-generated proxystub in order to authenticate the user to the webservice.

Since that class is C# specific, do you guys have any suggestions on how to do it in Java? I've looked through the autogenerated code but I couldn't find any other properties that look like they are related to authentication.
I appriciate any input on this since the people behind the webservice aren't very helpfull..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this answer
[Connect to a https site with a given p12 certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994944/connect-to-a-https-site-with-a-given-p12-certificate)

the HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory()); is the key. if after this point you open a secure connection to a wsdl service it will uses the credentials that you set up.