# Is it possible to make HTTPS request with client certificate from GAE Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, https, apache-httpclient-4.x

I would like to make a GET request, which expects client certificate(p12 file).

Methods tried.

1. Couldn't type cast `URLConnection` to `HttpsURLConnection`. Thus can't set use `setSSLSocketFactory` method.
2. Tried with Apache Http. Used the code given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994944/connect-to-a-https-site-with-a-given-p12-certificate#answer-26781595).

Please help.