# Use standard Java classes from JMeter using Groovy

Tags: java, ssl, groovy, jmeter

In JMeter I want to use a client certificate without all the [overhead](https://developer.ibm.com/mainframe/docs/how-to-test-your-apis/how-to-configure-jmeter-to-use-client-side-ssl/) of converting the certificate and do not forget to click on the SSL Manger Menu after JMeter restart.

I want the flexibility to use different certificates where ever needed.

The Java Solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7016969) looks very promising. I tried to use a JSR223 PreProcessor with Groovy. This fails with the first line. It was unable to import a standard Java Class.

```
2017-11-08 16:02:39,139 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script37.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class java.security.Keystore
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import java.security.Keystore;
```

What do I have to do to use standard Java classes?

The whole idea is based on a solution used in SoapUI.

```
import com.eviware.soapui.settings.SSLSettings
import com.eviware.soapui.model.settings.Settings
import com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI
Settings settings = SoapUI.getSettings()
settings.setString(SSLSettings.KEYSTORE, "../certificates/foo.p12")
settings.setString(SSLSettings.KEYSTORE_PASSWORD , "bar")
settings.reloadSettings()
```

Will something like this work in JMeter? Which client is used to send the HTTP samplers?

Answer (score 0):

These are not "standard Java classes", it looks like something from [SoapUI](http://soapui.org/)

You need to have these `com.eviware.soapui.*` classes under [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) in order to make it work. Once you add the necessary .jars JMeter restart will be required to pick them up. However I doubt you will be able to use this `com.eviware.soapui.model.settings.Settings` class instance in JMeter test.

There is an easier way to configure JMeter to use client-side certificates: just add the next lines to *system.properties* file:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12    
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=../certificates/foo.p12
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=bar
```

or pass them via [-D command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override) to JMeter startup script like:

```
jmeter -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=../certificates/foo.p12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=bar -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

See [How to Set Your JMeter Load Test to Use Client Side Certificates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-set-your-jmeter-load-test-use-client-side-certificates) article for more details on the approach.

Comment: I have read my question once again. I don’t see how you get the impression that I wanted to use SoapUI classes. As you can clearly read I want to import java.security.Keystore and this is indeed a standard Java class.